# BMT EJB does not make rollback

Tags: transactions, ejb, rollback

I have a Bean Maneged Transaction Stateless EJB. In this EJB there is a method where it is received a entity which will be updated. If a Exception is thrown, client will call another method in EJB to update this entity status to error.

EJB Interface

```
@Remote
interface EntityRemote {

    public void updateEntity(Entity entity) throws Exception;

    public void handleExcpetion(Entity entity, Exception exception);
}
```

EJB implmentation

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class EntitySessionBean implements EntityRemote {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction tx;

    public void updateEntity(Entity entity) throws Exception {
        tx.begin();
        try {
            // make some manipulation, which can throw some Exception

            enitityDAO.update(entity);

            // Some more manipulation

            tx.commit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void handleException(Entity entity, Exception exception) {
        log.error(exception);
        try {
            tx.begin();
            entity.setStatus(ERROR);
            enitityDAO.update(entity);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.exception(e1);
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

In client:

```
EntityRemote remote = // ...
Entity entity = // ...
try {
    remote.updateEntity(entity);
} catch (Exception e) {
    remote.handleException(entity, e);
}
```

My problem here occurs if in `updateEntity()` it is thrown some exception after update entity and before commit. I verified that in database not only modifications from `handleException()` are commited but also that done in `updateEntity()`. It is like rollback done in `updateEntity()` had no effect.

What is the problem here?